# how can i check if a variable is saved or not in the db?

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

I have this code:

```
$local_id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = dbquery("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `id` = ".$local_id." LIMIT 0, 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$video_id = $row["youtube_id"]; 
// the rest
}
```

how can i check if $local_id does not exist in the db and display an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
    //Show error 
}
```

Comment: +1 It seems like he also needs the data if it exists, so this is the best choice here. @m3tsys: can put these lines before the `while`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `videos` WHERE `id` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($local_id)
```

This query will return one number: **how many records have matched your query**. If this is **zero**, you surely know that there are no records with this ID.

This is more optimal than other solutions posted **in case you only want to check for the existence of the ID**, and don't need the data (if you use `SELECT * ...`, all the data will be unnecessarily sent from MySQL to you). Otherwise `mysql_num_rows()` is the best choice, as **@Ryan Doherty** correctly posted.

---

*Be sure to **ALWAYS** escape data that came from the outside (this time GET) before you put it into a query (`mysql_real_escape_string()` for MySQL).*

*If you fail to do so, you are a possible victim for [**SQL Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).*

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = dbquery("select count(*) from videos where id = ".$local_id." LIMIT 0, 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
if($row[0] == 0)
    echo 'error';
```

Comment: You have not formatted your code, and @Shef was nice enough to do it for you. Users with enough reputation are allowed to edit questions and answers (actually anyone can, but under a certain rep edits must be allowed by two more experienced users).

Comment: I appreciate that effort but I was curious to know if I wrote something wrong.

Comment: You can see what was changed if you click on the time (ex. `10 mins ago`) after the word `edited`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a $count variable and increment it in the while loop. After the loop, check the count, if it is 0, then echo an error message.